# C++: insert tuple in multiset with std::function, and keeping an order

Tags: c++, vector, insert, std-function, multiset

Quite simply, what's wrong with this piece of code?

```
    typedef std::function<double()>                             Event;
    typedef std::tuple <double, std::function<double()>>        Event_handle;

    std::multiset < Event_handle > event_multiset;
    std::vector < Event_handle > event_vector;
    void add_event_handler(double time, Event func_object)
    {
        // multiset version gives an error 
        // event_multiset.insert (std::make_tuple(time, func_object));
        // vector is ok
        event_vector.push_back(std::make_tuple(time, func_object));
    }
```

compiled using `g++ 4.7.2` - with command simply `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`

**Why I want to do this?**

The program is run in real time and the `add_even_handler` function includes a value of type `double` called `time` (note that `time` variable here has nothing to do with clock or actual time, it is just an increasing object of type double). Therefore when a user add some event it will be called at a certain time.

A multiset container under the standard would collate the objects in some order (usually, if not always, `std::less<T>`). Then looping over the container, I could call the `Event` upon increasing changes of variable `double time`.

**What is the problem?**

As KyleC has pointed out (see his answer), `std::function<>` is not understood by the compiler in what process to order

**How I've overcome the problem**

You learn something new everyday. The above code was a result of overthinking the problem by initially mixing `std::multiset` and `std::tuple`. `std::map<T,S>` or `std::multimap<T,S>` is also sorted by an associated `key` which in this case is of type `double`, which by default by the standard is again `std::less<T>`. So instead of the above, I've done something similar to the following

```
std::multimap <double, event> event_map;
void add_event_handler(double time, Event func_object)
{
    // multimap is ok
    event_map.insert(std::make_pair(time,func_object));
}
```

This is just written here in the event it may help people, albeit obvious but nonetheless.

Comment: can you post the relevant portion of the error?

Comment: @KyleC quick question, how do you output compiler errors to text file in g++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that multiset is ordered.

The error you are getting is:

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::function<_Fty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  
error C2088: '<' : illegal for class    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\tuple    52
```

The multiset doesn't know how to handle this because it does not know how to order the multiset.

> Internally, multiset containers keep all their elements sorted
>   following the criterion specified by its comparison object. The
>   elements are always inserted in its respective position following this
>   ordering.

What's wrong with using a vector?

-- Based on your comments, I think a map would suite your purposes nicely.

```
std::map < float, Event > event_map;
event_map.insert(std::make_pair(time, func_object));
```

Comment: Good point should have known that. What do you suggest in the following case. The program is run in real time and the `add_even_handler` function includes a value of type `double` called `time`. Therefore when a user add some event it will be called at a certain time. (note the time has nothing to do with clock, it is just an increasing variable). In a multiset I assumed the first element of `tuple` would automatically be sorted (which is obviously wrong like you said).

Comment: you should just use a std::map<float, Event> that should work for you as the float will be the 'key' which it will be sorted on.

Comment: Thanks, makes more sense now